# add value along with points in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code segment to mark the quantile points on a bivariate data distribution. The three red points correspond to quantiles of `0.1, 0.5 and 0.9` respectively. I would like to add the quantile value, i.e., `0.1, 0.5 and 0.9` along with their respective red points. How to do this in `matplotlib`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_samples = 2000
mu = np.array([5.0, 2.0])
r = np.array([
        [  3.40, -2.75],
        [ -2.75,  1.0]       
    ])
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, r, size=num_samples)
quantile_set = np.quantile(y, [0.1,0.5,0.9], axis=0)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(quantile_set[:,0],quantile_set[:,1],'ro',ms=4.5)
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution (play with `offset` to get the texts closer or far away from the points):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_samples = 2000
mu = np.array([5.0, 2.0])
r = np.array([
        [  3.40, -2.75],
        [ -2.75,  1.0]       
    ])
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, r, size=num_samples)
quantile_set = np.quantile(y, [0.1,0.5,0.9], axis=0)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(quantile_set[:,0],quantile_set[:,1],'ro',ms=4.5)

qtexts = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
offset = np.array([
    abs(y[:, 0].min() - y[:, 0].max()) * 0.05,
    abs(y[:, 1].min() - y[:, 1].max()) * 0.05
])
for q, t in zip(quantile_set, qtexts):
    plt.text(*(q+offset), t, color="r", horizontalalignment="right", verticalalignment="top")
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]